# Unable to calibrate variable area flowmeter to VDI/VDE 3513-2:2008

Tags: measurements, instrumentation, calibration

I'm seeking your expertise to resolve a calibration challenge with a Krohne DK-37 variable area flow meter. Despite repeated satisfactory calibrations by the German manufacturer, we're experiencing a consistent 10-15% deviation when using typical American flow meter calibration techniques. We believe a conversion or mathematical factor is missing, but haven't been able to resolve. Key details:

- Flow Range: 4.8 to 48 L/h
- Scale Reference Units: Normalized to air at 0°C and 1 atm
- Scale is calibrated to operating conditions of Nitrogen gas, 70°F, and 15.7 psia

The Calibration Methodology is according to VDI/VDE 3513-2.  Reference flow rates are calculated according to VDI/VDE 3513-1.

We have used both of the following standards to attempt the calibration, with similar results.

- Mass Flow Standard: DH Instruments/Fluke MOLBOX1 A700K with flow elements: 1E3-VCR-V-Q, 5E3-VCR-V-Q, 3E4-VCR-V-Q. (See Calibration Configuration Figure 2 placeholder)
- Volumetric Standard: BIOS/Mesa DryCal ML-800 with -3, -10, -24, and -44 cells. (See Calibration Configuration Figure 1 placeholder)

Various configurations have been used, but the desired configuration has the flow meter outlet to atmosphere with no pressure regulation.

We are required to adjust the as-measured flow (per VDI/VDE 3513-2) standard to the operating conditions using the following multiplication factor: SQRT[(0.97/SG) × (P/15.7) × (530/T)), where SG is specific gravity of the test medium (if not N2), P is process pressure (barometric with outlet unregulated), and T is test flow temperature in Rankine (about 75 °F for our lab).  This occurs in column 6, below.

The set of data corresponding to the described configuration (VA outlet to ambient, unregulated) is provided below.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.  This has us quite stymied and folks are near to throwing in the towel.  Any help or insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Feed it known conditions that are representative of what you would use it in.  How consistent are the results? Build a table. Fit to the table.